# How to read a column and write it as a row in python?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am trying to read a csv and then transpose one column into a row.

I tried following a tutorial for reading a csv and then one for writing but the data doesnt stay saved to the list when I try to write the row.

```
import csv

f = open('bond-dist-rep.csv')

csv_f = csv.reader(f)


bondlength = []

with open("bond-dist-rep.csv") as f:
    for row in csv_f:
        bondlength.append(row[1])

print (bondlength)

print (len(bondlength))

with open('joined.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_a = csv.writer (csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='"', 
quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    csv_a.writerow(['bondlength'])

with open('joined.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        print(row)
        print(row[0])



f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The matter is that you only read the first value of each line and write only a string in the new file.

In order to transpose the read lines, you can use the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function.

I also delete the first `open` function which is useless because of the good use of `with` for opening the file.

Here the final code:

```py
import csv
bondlength = []

with open("bond-dist-rep.csv") as csv_f:
    read_csv = csv.reader(csv_f)
    for row in read_csv:
        bondlength.append(row)
# delete the header if you have one
bondlength.pop(0)
with open('joined.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csv_a = csv.writer (csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for transpose_row in zip(*bondlength):
        csv_a.writerow(transpose_row)
```